# how to understand the gradient vector flow formula?

Tags: image-segmentation

Currently, I am learning [gradient vector flow](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ejsatta/statvis/project.pdf). I have one question about the calculation.

After Euler equations, the GVF can be found by solving the following formula:

[image]

Then, the paper said: "Equations (8) and (9) can be solved numerically by treating `u` and `v` as a function of time." The resulting equations are:

[image]

I have no idea how to obtain equation (10) from equation (8). Any suggestion is appreciated~~~